# Postgres CASE expression with multiple options for a single outcome

Tags: sql, postgresql, case

In a Ruby case statement you can say

```rb
name = case foo
       when 'bar', 'baz', 'bof' then 'Tom'
       when 'qux' then 'Jerry'
       end
```

and in a C/C++ switch statement you can stack cases on top of each other:

```c
switch(foo) {
      case 'bar' :
      case 'baz' :
      case 'bof' :

      ...
```

but is there anything similar in SQL/Postgres? Or do you have to spell it out for each option eg.

```sql
CASE foo
WHEN bar THEN 'Tom'
WHEN baz THEN 'Tom'
WHEN bof THEN 'Tom'
WHEN qux THEN 'Jerry'
END
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following syntax to write cases in PostgreSQL -

```
CASE
  WHEN <condition> THEN <return_value>
  WHEN <condition2> THEN <return_value>
  ELSE <return_value>
END
```

Example -

```
SELECT letter, 
(
  CASE 
    WHEN letter IN ('a', 'b', 'c') THEN 'a to c'
    WHEN letter = 'd'              THEN 'letter d'
    ELSE 'e to z'
  END
) AS letter_class
FROM alphabets;
```

Answer (score 2):

in sql it would be like below

```
CASE 
WHEN foo in( 'bar','bof','baz') THEN 'Tom'
WHEN foo ='qux' THEN 'Jerry'
END
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
CASE 
  WHEN foo IN (bar, baz, bof) THEN 'Tom'
  WHEN foo=qux THEN 'Jerry'
  ELSE ...
END
```